# where is the Form Web Part in Sharepoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

How do i add a form webpart in sharepoint designer 2010.
What i'm after is filter the list based on date using 2 textboxes
startdate and enddate.
Any ideas solution to this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The Data Form Web part in SharePoint 2007 is called Data View Web part in SharePoint 2010. You will be able to add the Data View web part into a page using SharePoint designer 2010.

These are the steps that would help you in acheiving the result.

- Convert Data View to XSLT Data View
- Create a Parameter for the Data View
- Filter the Data View Using the Parameter
- Drop Date Filter Web Part on Page
- Connect Parameter on Data View to Date Filter

There are certain blog posts which can help you achieve the date filtering that you are looking for.

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/09/16/sharepoint-date-filter-filtering-a-list-by-greater-than-or.aspx

http://davecavins.com/2009/09/filter-by-date-range/

Comment: Thanks Deepu.I'm not using Sharepoint Enterprise so i dont have OTB date filter.Right now i'm trying to use a html form(with a custom datepicker)

Answer (score 2):

You need to click on Insert DataView and then select Empty Data View It'll get the form WebPart
Then you need to click inside the DataForm WebPart and add a Data Source 
Once the data source is added you can select the columns you want to add for your view
Hope this helps